# REQUEST delivery method is not working - apply with monster

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have integrated [apply with monster](http://partner.monster.com/apply-with-monster) in my application

#### Problem

I am not getting response from monster after applying particularly for `REQUEST` delivery method

#### Note

It is working for `EMAIL` delivery method

#### Script for REQUEST Delivery Method

```
 <script id="awm" type="text/javascript"
    data-api-key="-----"
    data-companyname="test"
    data-jobtitle="test"
    data-joblocation="bangalore" 
    data-deliverymethod="REQUEST"
    data-onsuccess=gotoMonster()
    src="//login.monster.com/awm/en_US/awm.js">
</script>
```

Any suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue.

#### Working code as follows

```
<script id="awm" type="text/javascript"
   data-api-key="-----"
   data-companyname="test"
   data-jobtitle="test"
   data-joblocation="bangalore" 
   data-deliverymethod="REQUEST"
   data-deliveryformat="JSON"
   data-onsuccess='useMonster'
   src="//login.monster.com/awm/en_US/awm.js">
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

  function useMonster(params) {
    console.log(params);
  };

</script>
```